# Annoying bug at mysql table creation

Tags: mysql, database

Hi so I have this following statements that I want to use to create a mysql table.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (  
`UserID` INT(25) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,  
`Username` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL ,  
`Password` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL ,  
`EmailAddress` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL  
);  
CREATE TABLE `profile` (
`UserID` INT(25) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`Username` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL ,
`Position1` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL ,
`Position2` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL ,
`Position3` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL ,
`champion1` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL ,
`champion2` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL ,
`champion3` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL ,
`Level` INT(2) NOT NULL,
`League` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL ,
`Leaguename` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,
`lolking` VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,
`Bio` VARCHAR(140) NOT NULL,
);
```

But it fails to do so and gives me error message :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 8: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual      that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 16
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of the  last comma

```
`Bio` VARCHAR(140) NOT NULL
```

Comment: Yes this solve my problem
!

Comment: I will accept your answer in 12 minutes because stack doesn't let me do it now :D

Answer (score 2):

You have a comma "," where it shouldn't be:

```
 `Bio` VARCHAR(140) NOT NULL,
 );
```